# Obtain a a item id passed via in id attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of item with different and unique ids like `<div id="item-20110902" />`, `<div id="item-20110906" />` or `<div id="item-20110912" />`.

I have seen on various codes, but the problem is that I don't remember where, that there is an easy way to handle all the things after the "item-" without having to use RegEx, etc.

Is that true? If is it, how is done?

What I finally need is to obtain **20110902**, **20110906** or **20110912** inside the `click()` function I'll attach to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all divs starting with id `item`, you can use `starts with selector` eg `^=` :

```
$('div[id^="item"]')
```

Example Usage:

```
// change text color of all divs to red
$('div[id^="item"]').each(function(){
   $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: hi! It's not what I'm looking for. I can select that items, what I need is to get only "20110902" when attaching a click() event. Thank you!

Comment: @udexter:Inside your click handler for the div, you can use this code to get that number: `alert(this.id.split('-')[1])`

Answer (score 2):

add `class="items"`

and select it with

```
$(".items")
```

so result is

```
<div id="item-20110902" class="items" /> <div id="item-20110906" class="items"/> <div id="item-20110912" class="items"/>
```

or you can select them with `$("div[id^="item-"]);`

`^` means that it STARTS with it

Comment: hi! It's not what I'm looking for. I can select that items, what I need is to get only "20110902" when attaching a click() event. Thank you!

Comment: @udexter: add data-itemid="20110902" and select it $(this).attr('data-itemid')

Comment: There is no problem adding non-valid DOM attributes?